# I am trying to stack 1D features using scipy.hstack. But getting "ValueError: blocks must be 2-D" . Any suggestions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

```
print(key_standardized_train.shape)
(26800, 1)

from scipy.sparse import hstack

X_tr=hstack((song_duration_ms_standardized_train,acousticness_standardized_train,danceability_standardized_train))
```

> ************************************************************************* D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in
> bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
> 545
> 546     if blocks.ndim != 2:
> --> 547         raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
> 548
> 549     M,N = blocks.shape
>
> ValueError: blocks must be 2-D

Comment: what are these things you are trying to stack?  sparse matrices? shape? dtype?

Comment: The features are numerical and I have replaced the Nan values existing with column means and have standardized all columns. So they aren't sparse matrices anymore. Is there an alternative that i could use here to stack the features?

Comment: Don't use `sparce.hstack` if you aren't working with `scipy.sparse` matrices.

Comment: `scipy.sparse.hstack(blocks, format=None, dtype=None) -->
Stack sparse matrices horizontally (column wise)` as @hpaulj said, the matrices need to be sparse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stack matrices that aren't sparse you can use:

```
import numpy as np
X_tr = np.hstack(
              (song_duration_ms_standardized_train,
               acousticness_standardized_train,
               danceability_standardized_train)
             )
# or
X_tr = np.column_stack(
              (song_duration_ms_standardized_train,
               acousticness_standardized_train,
               danceability_standardized_train)
             )
```

Stack arrays in sequence horizontally (column wise) with `hstack`.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Stack 1-D arrays as columns into a 2-D array with `column_stack`.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html#numpy.column_stack